# windows 8 takes a long time to sleep. any way to speed it up?

Tags: windows-8, sleep

putting my new laptop to sleep, and it takes about 30 seconds before the power-button starts doing the "blinking" that lets me know it's sleeping.  during this time (between me pushing the sleep button and the blinking) my computer's screen is off and it's completely unusable.

resuming from sleep is snappy enough, but start-sleep to sleeping is frustrating slow.   any suggestions on how to speed it up?

---

some things i tried.....
I have tried disabing hibernate (just in case) but that has no effect.   also i tried the hybrid sleep but that also seems to have no effect.

i'm using a lenovo yoga 13, and so also tried the oem's specific power configuration tool, but that also has no effect on my problem.

Comment: do you have a lot of disk activities during that 30 seconds period? also, have you tried to go into sleep mode right after a fresh boot up?

Comment: i didn't look, but i think no.   i wasn't running any apps (i didn't install any)  however i can't say that windows wasn't doing something on it's own.

Comment: fyi my mitigation is to only have it fall asleep after 5 min inactivity, instead of the normal "close lid"

Comment: Are you sure hybrid sleep is completely disabled (it is enabled for desktop PCs by default)? This sounds awfully like it saves RAM to HDD, then sleeping. It can also be pre-standby cleanup, but that shouldn't take 30 seconds unless the system has been up for a long time with a lot of activity.

Answer (score 1):

This is a either a compatibility issue with your chipset or something as simple as changing the BIOS "suspend" setting. If it's a chipset issue, consider making sure you have all the latest driver updates from Windows and your manufacturer.

To check your BIOS settings, [see this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/225833/Tweak_Your_Windows_PCs_Sleep_Mode.html).

I had this same issue and found a it was two things; BIOS setting and too many processes to suspend.

Comment: thanks for the help,  my machine (lenovo yoga 13) unfortunatly doesn't have power options in bios, and i was having this issue with a default install of win8.

so maybe a chipset issue (i installed all the latest drivers)

Answer (score 0):

It could have been some devices/drivers requesting that the computer didn't enter into sleep mode.

Referring to http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/36103-windows-8-1-shut-down-sleep-issues.html#post329714 as it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue where "sometimes" it was taking minutes to go to sleep.

My PC was most of the time using more than 90% of RAM (but less than 96%).

After adding more RAM the issue went away completely, so the answer in my case was:
' It will take long time to go to sleep if it is swapping or has lots of stuff in the swapping space '

Answer (score 0):

Look at the event viewer and enable "verbose shutdown" in the registry.

It might be some faulty application that crashes or a driver that somehow doesn't want to shut down.